# In VS/VB, system.windows.forms.control is overiding microsoft.vb.strings module, has anyone had this issue before?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I suddenly get an error in Visual Studio/VB where system.windows.forms.control is overiding microsoft.vb.strings module, such that code that was fine yesterday now throws an error.

dim cat as string="herd of cats"

dim slice as string=Left(cat,4)

throws an error on Left, "Public Overloads Property Left As Integer' has no parameters and its return type cannot be indexed."

while,

dim cat as string="herd of cats"

dim slice as string=strings.Left(cat,4)

is fine.  I assume it is being overloaded by system.windows.forms.control.left property for some reason and I dont know how to fix it or why its happening. I fully uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio, reinstalled the .net framework to try and fix the problem but it still exists in new blank programs. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Left` is ambiguous; it exists within both the String class and the Form class & as the code is (presumably) inside the Form then the "most local" `Left` wins.

`Left` itself is a holdover from VB6 & you should not really be using it (the behavior you see is [documented in the remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.left?view=netframework-4.7.2)).

Switch to:

```
dim slice as string = cat.Substring(0, 4)
```

Comment: Thank you, on seeing your mention of "form" I remembered that I had moved the offending code from a module into a form class.  Also good to know that "Left" is depricated.  I didnt know that.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Dim slice As String = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(cat), String.Empty, cat.Substring(0, Math.Min(cat.Length, 4)))` to emulate the `Left` function?